# Xively data in a spreadsheet

Tags: arduino, xively

Hi I am new to using Xively and working on a project for the [Craftsbury Outdoor Center](http://www.craftsbury.com/).  I have a few temperature and humidity sensors hooked up and streaming to Xively from an Arduino, but we think it would be useful to have the data also offline and in a spreadsheet.

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can download your xively data in CSV format (readable by spreadsheet programs) with the [REST API](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/data/read/), just be careful not to download too much too fast (exceed the quotas).

After replacing `YOUR_*` values with your actual values, this should get you started:

```
curl --request GET "http://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/YOUR_FEED/datastreams/YOUR_CHANNEL.csv?key=YOUR_API_KEY&start=2013-12-22&duration=24hours&interval=900&limit=100&interval_type=discrete" > data.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Vasek. Any way to get the response as text/csv instead of text/plain? I'd prefer a direct browser download for my use case.